# i try to make gap interval or say add constant value in array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i just want to show time gap i.e 9:00 9:20 9:40 (20 minutes gap)

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">

<div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:5">
9:00
</div>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Main', function() {
    var start_time = 1;
    var end_time = 10;
    var step = 2;

    for (var i=start_time; i<end_time; i+=step) {
        input.push(i);
        return $scope.input;
    };
});
```

Comment: can you use 3rd party?

Comment: no i just wanted to do in angularjs and i don't know right now how to deal

Comment: Pitty, because with [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) you can do it easylly

Comment: how momentjs will help

Comment: Take a look at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/ for example - Allow you to _Mutates the original moment by adding time._

Comment: anyone have similar code as i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something.

Here is a link to a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fugafeyafo/edit?html,js,output

```
<div ng-repeat="d in timeArray">{{d | date: "HH:mm"}}</div>
```

In javascript.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Main',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.timeArray = [];
    var startDate = new Date().getTime();
    [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(n, i){
        $scope.timeArray.push(new Date(startDate + n * 20 * 60 * 1000));
    });
}]);
```

Output:

> 22:42
>
> 23:02
>
> 23:22
>
> 23:42
>
> 00:02

Comment: code not executed only showing in output {{d | date: "HH:mm"}}

Comment: as i need only time which is in gap for 20 minutes                                                  9:00AM 9:20AM 9:40AM

Comment: there is 20 minutes difference in every time.

Comment: exactly as i need your output but code is not showing any output

Comment: I added link to working code in my answer. http://jsbin.com/fugafeyafo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: $scope.timeArray.push(new Date(startDate + n * 20 * 60 * 1000)); will u told me something about this line

Comment: startDate is time in milliseconds. I am adding 20 min (1 * 20 * 60 * 1000), 40 min (2 * 20 * 60 * 1000), 60 min (3 * 20 * 60 * 1000) and so on. `60` for seconds in one minute and `1000` for milliseconds in a second. `Date` constructor takes milliseconds from `epoch`. I hope you know what is `epoch`